# Why does the progression of values of $\sin(x)$ seem so arbitrary?

Tags: trigonometry

I don't know how to ask this in a way that doesn't sound a little stupid, but what I mean is, the progression of values of say, sin(x) seems really arbitrary. Is there an intuitive way to understand why, for example:

```
   x            y
-------   -------------
sin(45) = 0.85090352453
sin(46) = 0.90178834764
```

What is determining the amounts that Y goes up or down by as X changes? And even better, is there something (fairly accessible to non-mathematicians) I can read that can explain this sort of thing in a very intuitive way? I don't want to prove that it works, just understand how come. Thanks!

Comment: Those sine values are probably not the sine values you think they are.

Comment: [This](https://www.geogebra.org/m/cNEtsbvC) might help.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1m9p9iubMLU. This is an explanation of the definition of trigonometric functions to people new to the topic. I don't know what your background is, but if possible look at videos for Taylor Series to find infinite polynomials which describe the trigonometric functions.

Comment: Note: sinus of 45 radians = 0.8509, not 45 degrees ...

Comment: I think it's better to focus on what sine values _are_, rather than how they change.

Comment: Once it is appreciated that sine value is length of projection on a rotating radius in a fixed radius it feels less arbitrary

Comment: @Narasimham What does that mean? I only know sine as, given a certain angle in a triangle, the ratio of the other side over the hypotenuse.

Comment: The fixed radius is hypotenuse. Projection on y-axis is the other side.Their ratio is the sine of angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean to be working in radians, because $\sin 45$ is  a little bit arbitrary.  So, if $\sin 45$ seems arbitrary, it is because $45$ is a bit arbitrary in the units you have chosen.

Lets explain what all of this means.

[image]

45 represents the point you would be if you traveled along the circumference of the circle in a counter clockwise direction a distance 45 units.

That is 7 full revolutions plus about 1/6 an additional revolution.

$45 = 14\pi + 1.02$

I have marked approximately where 45 and 46 lie on the unit circle.

$\sin 45$ is the distance that point is above the $x$ axis.
$\cos 44$ is the distance to the right of the $y$ axis.

$\sin 46$ is nearly the same height above the $x$, axis.

Other things that make $\sin x$ appear a little arbitrary... Except of $0$ if $x$ is rational $\sin x$ will irrational (transcendental in fact).

Some other rules you can live by.

$-1\le \sin x \le 1$

$\sin (x+\pi) = -\sin x\\
\sin -x = -\sin x\\
\sin (x+2\pi) = \sin x$

$|\sin x - \sin y| \le |x-y|$

You can find $\sin x$ by plugging into this formula.

$\sin x = \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac {x^{2n+1}}{2n+1!}$  Which works very well for small values of $x$ but would take a long time to converge for a vale of $x$ as big as $45.$

but since $\sin 45 =\sin 1.02$ you can plug $1.02$ into the formula and it will converge much faster.

I hope this helps.

If we are working in degrees:

[image]

$46^\circ$ is much closer to $45^\circ$ than we were when we were working in radius.

$360^\circ = 2\pi$ radians

or 1 degree $= \frac {\pi}{180}$ radians.

or 1 radian $\approx 57$ degrees.

$45^\circ$ is a special angle.  We can use it to construct an isosceles right triangle and find $\sin 45^\circ$ exactly

$\sin 45^\circ = \frac {\sqrt {2}}{2} \approx 0.707$

Most other angles are still problematic.

$\sin 46^\circ \approx 0.719$

since the angle is small. If we travel from $(\cos 45^\circ, \sin 45^\circ)$ tangent to the circle the distance equivalent to 1 degree, we will arrive very nearly at $(\cos 46^\circ, \sin 46^\circ)$

The slope of the tangent is the negative reciprocal of the slope of the radius.

We travel vertically $\cos 45(\frac {\pi}{180})$ and to the left $\sin 45(\frac {\pi}{180})$

In degrees
$|\sin (x+1) - \sin x| \le \frac {\pi}{180}$

Comment: It might be worth mentioning degrees.  Use of $45$ suggests that the OP had degrees in mind.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me with this! I really like this community and the work people put it on the answers. I'll never approach the skill you have but I'm having a blast learning. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using radians rather than degrees.  Degrees are most common in day to day use (a full circle is $360$).  Serious maths usually uses radians (a full circle is $2 \pi$).  Calculators that support sine usually offer both but the default varies.  If you did not intend to use radians then check the instructions for a degree mode.  Computing languages also vary but radians are common.  An option for degrees is less common but it can be handled.  If $\theta$ is your angle in degrees then use $\sin(\theta  \pi / 180)$.

As Doug M explains , $1$radian is a quite large and fairly arbitrary amount, around $57.3$ degrees.  He explains the consequences well.

If you switch to degrees then it will look quite different.  $45$ is quite special in degrees and its $\sin$ is $\frac{\sqrt(2)}{2}$ which is approximately $0.7071$.  $1$ degree is fairly small.  If you calculate $\sin$ for $45, 46, 47, ...$ then the pattern should be clearer.  It will grow approximately at a constant rate but gradually slowing until it reaches $90$ when it will reach its maximum of $1$ and then it will start to fall.

Alternatively, go back to radians but use a smaller step e.g. $0.01, 0.02, 0.03, ...$.  Again, you will see a pattern.